# Energy method for $u_{tt}-\Delta u=-u^3$ to show uniquness

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, maximum-principle

Assume the following problem:
\begin{align}
u_{tt}-\Delta u &= -u^3\quad \text{in}\ \Omega,\ t>0\\
u&=0 \quad \text{for}\ \partial \Omega \\
u(\cdot,0)&=u_0 \\
u_t(\cdot, 0)&=0
\end{align}
It should be proven, that there exists at most one classical solution.

So assuming that $\omega =u,v$ are classical solutions, I multiply both sides with $\omega_t=(u-v)_t$ and do a partial integration, obtaining
$$0= \int_{\Omega} \omega_{tt}\omega_t - \nabla \omega \nabla \omega_t +(u^3-v^3)(u-v)_t dx$$
Now with the product rule I get
$$\int_{\Omega} \omega_{tt}\omega_t - \nabla \omega \nabla \omega_t dx=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega} \omega_t^2 +|\nabla \omega|^2 dx$$

The nonlinear term is making trouble now. I want to get a nonnegative term containing (u-v) whose derivate after $t$ gives me $(u^3-v^3)(u-v)_t$. I played around a bit, but couldn't come up with anything useful.

I have seen tricks in similar problems like: $(u^3-v^3)(u-v)=(u-v)^2\frac{1}{2}(u^2+v^2+(u+v)^2)$, however the time derivate gives me trouble utilizing that.

Another approach I have seen is using the mean value theorem that gives us a $\xi(x,t) \in [min(u, v), max(u, v)]$, so that $(u^3-v^3)=\xi^2(u-v)$. However, since $\xi$ is dependant on time, I can't neither find nonnegative term.

Would be realy grateful if someone could enlighten me.

Comment: @Mattos I do not see how that is helping me though: I would get $\frac{1}{2}(u^4-v^4)$. In the end I want to argue that the time derivate of the  integral is zero everywhere. I can't really argue why this has to hold. I know that $(u-v)(0)=0$ and $\nabla(u-v)(0)=0$ in $\Omega$ but I fail to see why this should be the case for $u^4-v^4$. So the idea was to somehow factor out (u-v) and still have some nonnegative factor multiplied with it.

Comment: Are you trying to use the conservation of energy because someone suggested that you use the "energy method?" Because for nonlinear wave equations, "energy method" is an overloaded term. In this area, to use the "energy method" often means to prove local wellposedness in a high-regularity Sobolev space via contraction mapping. If this is done, the uniqueness of the solution (as well as locally Lipschitz dependence on the initial data) in Sobolev spaces (and hence for classical solutions) comes as a direct consequence.

Comment: @GyuEunLee Ultimately I'm trying to show uniqueness. In my lecture I have only learned this one method to show uniqueness: The energy functional is calculated and shown to be constant in $t$ for the difference of two classical solutions, so I guess this is what you mean by conservation of energy.

Comment: @GEO But that's precisely the problem - the difference of two solutions will not exhibit constant energy. That sort of thing can work for a linear PDE since the difference of solutions will satisfy a linear PDE with conserved energy, but here we specifically have a nonlinear PDE, so there is no reason to believe that the difference of solutions satisfies conservation of energy (and generally it doesn't). What I am saying is that the term "energy method" in the context of nonlinear wave equations can have nothing to do whatsoever with conservation laws...

Comment: (cont.) What the "energy method" typically refers to in this setting is the local existence and uniqueness theory in high-regularity Sobolev spaces. Solutions in these function spaces can be constructed via Picard iteration in the appropriate space. One can get the uniqueness of classical solutions either essentially as a consequence of the Picard iteration process, or by directly proving that the difference of two solutions satisfies a Gronwall inequality, all without ever referring to conservation laws. In fact, in dimension 1 you can even do this in spaces where energy conservation fails.

Comment: @GyuEunLee This example is from an old exam at my university. In the first part one had to show that the energy functional is constant in time and in the second part the uniqueness of classical solutions, so I assumed there is a trick like e.g. using the mean value theorem to use the energy method.

Would you mind showing me how to do it with the Gronwall inequality?

Comment: @Mattos Yes I did show that already prior to asking the question, however I am failing to see how that really helps me.

Comment: The idea would be to covert the equation for the difference $u-v$ into an integral equation. This can be done using Duhamel's formula; often for equations of wave type it is convenient to use the half-wave operator instead. Since $u-v$ appears in both sides of the equation, estimating all terms in $H^s$ for sufficiently high Sobolev regularity $s$, one can essentially bound $\|u-v\|_{H^s}$ by itself, after which you are in position to use Gronwall. The technical details are a bit long for here; I'd refer you to *Nonlinear Dispersive Equations* by Tao.